# Creating email accounts on Bitnami Stack (Apache + LAMP)

Tags: apache, azure, bitnami, webmin

I'll preface this by saying I'm very new to working with webservers, so hopefully this is not a drop-dead simple issue - but I've yet to find a solution for creating an email account for my domain.

I was trying to create a new email address under my webserver domain due to purchasing an SSL certificate. I'm using [www.ssls.com](https://www.ssls.com/) to provide the cert, and the final step is to provide an email account for the approver email to receive the cert.  However, I can only choose to send the cert to a list of generic emails on my domain, such as admin@my_domain_name.com.  This seemed like a straightforward issue, but have yet to find a solution to create a new user account/email to receive the certificate.

I tried using the [Bitnami document to add Webmin](https://wiki.bitnami.com/BitNami_Cloud_Hosting/FAQ#How_can_I_add_webmin_to_my_server_on_Bitnami_Cloud_Hosting.3f) to my webserver to manage emails, but I seem to be getting issues accessing the files under etc/webmin/apache due to permission issues, even though I'm logging into as the root user.

Am I missing something extremely simple in this process?  It seems like setting up an email on the domain should be a relatively straightforward process, but I've yet to find a way to do this. The webserver is hosted on Azure using the Bitnami LAMP stack and Apache.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

Your domain provider probably gave you an email address like admin@yoursite.com. You should check with them.

You could also try to enter to your provider admin panel and see if you can configure your email.